# EC2 Linux : Error:Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Few months back i have purchased AWS server and created one amazon linux instance(ec2-user) under its one year free subscription (t2-micro). I have been using instance for file input and output operation as well as server configuration via putty and filezilla as well. But recently when i tried connecting it via ppk file it showed me this error in filezilla

```
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

The same type of error occurred when i tried to connect to via putty also.

I did a workaround about this issue and found so many links but i am not getting how to resolve the issue. Some answer says i need to update the public key over the instance but as i am not able to connect to instance, how that could be done i am not able to understand. At this moment i have only access to my AWS Console account and nothing else.

Any views over this are Welcome...

Comment: perhaps you are just using wrong username?

Comment: try `centos`, `ubuntu`, `ec2-user` and `root`

Comment: Thanks but its ec2-user username that i am using from long time to access and even i tried before with root as you said....but it asks me to login via ec2-user and exit me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take Snapshot of that machine and convert it as a AMI and upload to your aws console .Then Create new instance using that AMI.

Comment: Could you make it more simple by steps if you have

Comment: EC2 service --> select instance --> click on action --> create image .Then go to Ami -> select ami --> click on lanch button that's enough

Comment: I have created this following your steps. The new instance got created! Will it copy all the previous instance configurations and content????

Comment: Wow it works like charm...i have one more thing to ask??? now what i have to do to make my previous key work here. Creating AMI under free-tier one year subscription is free???

Comment: Do u  have .pub Key

Comment: While creating the instance from snapshot use your previous key.I won't be one year based on hours.They will provide 756 hours for free user. If u use more than one instance it will be over before itself.

Comment: I have generated the private key via puttygen, no idea about public key

Comment: while creating instance using ami use your previous key (what you used for your previous instance).

Answer (score -1):

No possibility to connect to instance via FileZilla. Try to connect via alternative ways, like terminal. That may get you a step further by solving problem and give possibility to update key as mentioned in your question.

Might sound confusing. In my case connection via several ways is running. Only FileZilla doesn't want to. If you finally found a solution to question at all please tell [me](https://superuser.com/questions/1206033/filezilla-no-supported-authentication-method-to-connect-ec2-instance-sublime-s).

Comment: Ideally speaking..it is not even getting connected via putty too...what else different tools could help could you let me know??